# 'IADsLargeInteger' is ambiguous in the namespace 'ActiveDs'

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll

i am working i a project in VB language and i am facing this type of error when i try to compile it 
"'IADsLargeInteger' is ambiguous in the namespace 'ActiveDs'"
This is the part of code giving me the error:

```
   Function GetLargeInteger(ByVal val As Int64) As 
    IADsLargeInteger
    Dim largeInt As New ActiveDs.LargeInteger

    largeInt.HighPart = CType((val >> 32), Integer)
    val = val << 32
    val = val >> 32
    largeInt.LowPart = (Convert.ToInt32(val))
    Return largeInt
End Function
```

and also i have imported:

```
Imports Dar.DAL
Imports DbShare
Imports System.DirectoryServices
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Imports System.IO
Imports Dar.BLL.Interfaces
Imports Dar.DAL.Repositories
Imports Dar.BLL.Services
Imports System.Security.Principal
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Globalization
Imports Elmah
Imports System.Configuration
Imports ActiveDs
```

Please help because i am not getting what is going wrong

Comment: The `Imports` directives at the top of the file matter, we can't see them.  The return type declaration of the function looks very wonky in the snippet, keep it on one line and type the full name, including the ActiveDs. prefix

Comment: @HansPassant i edited my question so now you can see all my imports

Answer (score 0):

What the error message is telling you is that the `IADsLargeInteger` is defined more than once somewhere and the compiler doesn't know which one to use.  You either have to remove one definition (the imports statement of one) or point exactly to the one you want to use.  I assume the one you want to use is contained in `ActiveDS` given the `largeint` declaration, so change your function to return that one:

```
Function GetLargeInteger(ByVal val As Int64) As ActiveDS.IADsLargeInteger
    Dim largeInt As New ActiveDs.LargeInteger

    largeInt.HighPart = CType((val >> 32), Integer)
    val = val << 32
    val = val >> 32
    largeInt.LowPart = (Convert.ToInt32(val))
    Return largeInt
End Function
```